# How to add "view:source" option in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, prettify

I know my title isn't that descriptive so let me try to explain it here.

In my blog I want to add an option for user that when he clicks a small button named `view:source` he gets the the source code in `raw format`. I am using `prettify.js` for syntax highlighting and it automatically creates a textbox around my source code with the below defined css:

```
pre.prettyprint { 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono";
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #EBECE4
}
```

Now, in that text-box like structure I just want to add an option/button to view the source in raw format. The feature am talking about can be seen in this  [dzone post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-using-project).

Comment: what's the point of using a syntax highlighting plugin if you're going to make the users open a popup window anyways?

Comment: @jbabey: I actually wanted to provide an option so that user can copy the source code on `clipboard` but I read that this feature has a `flash` dependancy. So, I thought why not pop-up a window with source code in `raw-format` and user can just do `Ctrl-A/C` to copy it.

Comment: @A.M.K: Till now I am only using `html and css`. So, no fancy stuff other than prettify.js.

Comment: @Noob good syntax highlighter plugins support copy/paste just fine, you don't need to open a popup window.

Comment: @jbabey: The problem is `prettify` doesn't and yes I agree that highlighter like `syntax-highlighter` works good for copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this, obviously changing it from a button, having better positioning and element targeting and using an actual version of prettify.js instead of just the output:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/9YXxP/

JavaScript:

```
var code = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerText;

var elm = document.getElementById("clickmeforpopup");

elm.onclick = function() {
    popup = window.open("", "popup");
    popup.document.body.innerText = code;
};​
```

Comment: +1 This is a good solution but with a small problem. For languages like python it will loose all its formatting/indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider another library that supports that functionality rather than implementing it yourself. In this article you can find syntax hightlighters that show raw code like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) or [beautyOfCode](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/beautyofcode-jquery-plugin-for-syntax-highlighting/)

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/